# SQL Server query pulls two different rows from same table

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to write a query that pulls the uploader and the downloader from a users table, but I am unable to do that since my WHERE condition can only pick one user ID. In the provided code, the downloader ID is given in the query (For example 10), but the uploader ID is supposed to be found by the query since the uploader's ID is stored in tbl_files in a column called user_id.

I have tried writing two conditions but they end up both applying for tbl_files to have the uploader as the downloader

```sql
SELECT
    tbl_files.id,
    tbl_sessions.[name] as session,
    tbl_users.id as user_id,
    tbl_users.username as downloader
FROM
    tbl_files
INNER JOIN
    tbl_downloads
ON 
    tbl_files.id = tbl_downloads.file_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_sessions
ON
    tbl_sessions.id = tbl_files.session_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_users
ON
    tbl_users.id = tbl_downloads.user_id
WHERE tbl_users.id = 10
```

http://prntscr.com/o2voct

Comment: Could you post DDLs for sample data, also specify the expected result as well.

Comment: *"I have tried writing two conditions but they end up both applying for tbl_files to have the uploader as the downloader "* I assume you tried an `AND`? Sounds like you want an `OR`. This definatly sounds like the need to an `OR` or `IN` clause, as you're looking for rows where the user downloaded **or** uploaded the file. Without knowing what your data looks like, then that's the best I can offer in help, however.

Comment: I was about to provide sample data but already got an answer, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add one more join with `tbl_users` table to fetch Uploader details.
Try this-

```
SELECT
    tbl_files.id,
    tbl_sessions.[name] as session,
    tbl_users.id as user_id,
    tbl_users.username as downloader,
    upld.id as upload_id,
    upld.username as uploader
FROM
    tbl_files
INNER JOIN
    tbl_downloads
ON 
    tbl_files.id = tbl_downloads.file_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_sessions
ON
    tbl_sessions.id = tbl_files.session_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_users
ON
    tbl_users.id = tbl_downloads.user_id
INNER JOIN
    tbl_users as upld
ON
    upld.id = tbl_files.user_id
WHERE tbl_users.id = 10
```